# How to reclaim Memory after a PThread exit?

Tags: ubuntu, pthreads

I am creating a thread in Ubuntu using `pthread_create`function. I have observed through top command that once the thread is getting created, virtual memory is increased, but even after the thread exits, that memory is not getting decreased. I have even used `pthread_detach()` [as per `pthread_detach` manual, it automatically releases all the resources it acquired during creation], but still got the same result. Please find the example code below:

```
size_t  const thread_no = 1;
char mess[] = "This is a test";

void *message_print(void *ptr){
  int error = 0;
  char *msg;

  /* Detach the thread */
  error = pthread_detach(pthread_self());
  /* Handle error if any */

  printf("THREAD: This is the Message %s\n", mess);
}

int main(void) {
  int error = 0;
  size_t i = 0;
  /* Create a pool of threads */
  pthread_t thr[thread_no];
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  error = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

  for(i = 0; i < thread_no; i++) {
    error = pthread_create( &(thr[i]), &attr, message_print, (void *) mess);
    /* Handle error */
  }
  printf("MAIN: Thread Message: %s\n", mess);
  while(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's really up to the operating system when resources are actually reclaimed by the OS. You may or may not see the effect right away. The OS may hold on to the resource in case you want to spawn another thread (or not). It may hold it until it is actually needed for something else.

Even though you have "released" it, the OS may not have a need to actually reclaim it right away.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I solved the problem just by setting the detach attribute

```
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
```

I hope it solves your's too.